# Datatables Filter columns on background colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, colors, datatables

I have a table in jQuery [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables), pretty standard stuff but I use `rowcallback` to change the background color of certain cells depending on criteria. This happens to 3 columns 6,7 and 8. The `rowcallback` works perfects and shades cells as I wanted.

However, on some days I can have a lot of data in my table so I would like to filter/search via a button to show only rows where  cols 6,7 and 8  have a background color of lime.

I've tried to use the standard search and include the term "lime" or the css

```
table.columns(8).search("style=background-color: lime").draw();
```

```
rowCallback: function (row, data, index) {
    if ((data["nextover"] > 85 && data["sno"] > 14) || (data["nextover"] > 70 && data["sno"] > 10 && data["time"] >= 70) || (data["nextover"] > 55 && data["sno"] > 5 && data["time"] >= 81)) {
        $(row)
        .find('td:eq(6)')
        .css('background-color', 'lime');
    } else {
        $(row)
        .find('td:eq(6)')
        .css('background-color', 'mistyrose');
    }
    var chars = data["pi2"].split(':');
    if (Number(chars[0]) + Number(chars[1]) > 15) {
        $(row)
        .find('td:eq(8)')
        .css('background-color', 'lime');
    } else {
        $(row)
        .find('td:eq(8)')
        .css('background-color', 'mistyrose');
    }
    var chars2 = data["pi1"].split(':');
    if (Number(chars2[0]) + Number(chars2[1]) > 70) {
        $(row)
        .find('td:eq(7)')
        .css('background-color', 'lime');
    } else {
        $(row)
        .find('td:eq(7)')
        .css('background-color', 'mistyrose');
    }
}
```

What I would like is a button that I can click and it will only show cells where any one of cols 7,8 and 9 have a lime background color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom search [plug-in](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search) may solve your problem. With that you may filter rows based on whether row has cells having necessary class (e.g. 'lime'):

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((_,__,rowIdx) => $(dataTable.row(rowIdx).node()).has('td.lime').length || !$('#showLime').hasClass('limeOnly'));
```

So, the button you mention, needs simply to redraw the table.

Complete **demo** you may find below:

```js
//src data
const srcData = [
  {item: 'apple', qty: 15},
  {item: 'banana', qty: 8},
  {item: 'mango', qty: 4},
  {item: 'kiwi', qty: 11},
  {item: 'pear', qty: 12}
];

//datatables initialization
const dataTable = $('table').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'item', data: 'item'},
    {
      title: 'qty', 
      data: 'qty',
      createdCell: (td,_,rowData) => rowData.qty < 10 ? $(td).addClass('lime') : true
    }
  ]
});

//custom filtering based on matching class 'lime'
//and 'show/hide' button state (class 'limeOnly')
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((_,__,rowIdx) => $(dataTable.row(rowIdx).node()).has('td.lime').length || !$('#showLime').hasClass('limeOnly'));

//toggle class 'limeOnly' on the button and re-draw table
$('#showLime').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('limeOnly');
  dataTable.draw();
});
```

```css
.lime {background-color: lime}
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" /><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script></head><body><table></table><button id="showLime">Show/Hide lime</button></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I get the event propogation and whilst its complictaed it makes sense, I changed my event handler as you recommended but im still seeing only the results on the first page

`code`
    $('body').on('change', '#showLime', function () {
       $(this).toggleClass('limeOnly');
        table.draw();
     });
`code`

This should now work as im applying it to the body of the document which should cover all pages, however it still only returns the results on the first page

Comment: Hi Yevgen, no still not working, codepen here

https://codepen.io/mikehobson/pen/RwbGJJX

Comment: @MikeHobson : I don't get the problem - your 'on/off' switch perfectly filters highlighted entries back and forth regardless of the current table page. Can you explain in more details what works not as expected?

Comment: Hi Yevgen, when I run that codepen and do nothing but click the on/off switch I only see 1 result and that is a result from the first 10. If I change the page size to 100 and click the swich I see 4 and if I move from page 1 to page 2 and click the switch I see 2. 
It seems to me that the data is not loaded until its displayed and once loaded then the switch works as expected .

Comment: I currently pass a string like this into variable pi2 :"20:30", I split and if its over 15 I highlight

 `var chars = data["pi2"].split(':'); 
if(Number(chars[0])+Number(chars[1])>15) 
{ $(row).find('td:eq(8)').addClass('lime'); }`

looking at your example Im not sure how this would work It would seem to suggest I need to add in the colulms section 
`{ data: 'pi2', 
createdCell: (td,_,rowData) => rowData.pi2 > 15 ? $(td).addClass('lime') : true }`


When I add this datatables fails

Comment: Apolgies my JS is really poor, Id much prefer PHP :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, your code is really clear and I can now see exactly what you have done, I really have learned a lot, thank you